# Elasticsearch - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I'm trying to connect a java client to my elasticsearch server. 
The version of elasticsearch is 2.4.0.
This server has a special configuration that's why I use port 10700 instead of 9300 in order to connect.
(When I try "telnet serveraddress 10700" I succeed).

As you'll see below, I have an error and I don't know how to resolve it.

Can you help me, please ?

Thanks.

My Code :

```
public void connexionToEs() throws UnknownHostException {
    String clusterName = "xxx";
    String serverAddress = "xxx";

    try{
        Settings settings = Settings.builder()
                .put("cluster.name", clusterName)
                .put("client.transport.sniff", true)
                .build();
        TransportClient client = new PreBuiltTransportClient(settings);
        client.addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName(serverAddress), 10700));

        SearchResponse response = client.prepareSearch().execute().actionGet();
        String output = response.toString();
        System.out.println(output);
        client.close();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

My dependencies :

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
  <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
  <version>2.4.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
  <artifactId>transport</artifactId>
  <version>5.0.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.7</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
  <version>2.7</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>log4j-web</artifactId>
  <version>2.6.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>log4j-to-slf4j</artifactId>
  <version>2.6.2</version>
</dependency>
```

My error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/elasticsearch/plugins/ActionPlugin
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at org.elasticsearch.transport.client.PreBuiltTransportClient.<clinit>(PreBuiltTransportClient.java:54)
at fr.solocal.dao.impl.CentralDAOImpl.connexionToEs(CentralDAOImpl.java:422)
at fr.solocal.App.main(App.java:28)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.elasticsearch.plugins.ActionPlugin
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 20 more
```

Comment: You have different version of elasticsearch and transport client.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! Yes I know, but I red the elasticsearch version depend of that installed on the server. So I tried with an elastic version 5.0.0 but the issue is others thread errors...

Answer (score 0):

As @Roma Khomyshyn mentioned, Spring Data Elasticsearch only support transport client currently, but the version of Elasticsearch server and transport client must be **the same**. That's why you got unexpected error like this one.

A possible solution is another Spring Data implementation using JEST client - https://github.com/VanRoy/spring-data-jest